# ExException in thread “main” java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /home cannot be a directory

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, maven-2, apache-spark

HI i am running word count exercise in spark java. When i execute in hdfs i am getting like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /home/karun cannot be a directory.
at org.apache.spark.HttpFileServer.addFileToDir(HttpFileServer.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.HttpFileServer.addJar(HttpFileServer.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addJar(SparkContext.scala:1162)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$11.apply(SparkContext.scala:276)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$11.apply(SparkContext.scala:276)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:276)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>  
at WordCount.WordCount.WordCountSpark.main(WordCountSpark.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

This is full execution structure

```
 spark-submit --jars $(echo "$JARFILE,./lib_bd/lucene-core-3.6.0.jar,./lib_bd/hive-jdbc-0.13.1-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/hive-metastore-0.13.1-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/hive-common-0.13.1-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/hive-contrib-0.13.1-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/hive-cli-0.13.1-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/hive-exec-0.13.1-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/hive-service-0.13.1-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar,./lib_bd/opennlp-maxent-3.0.3.jar,./lib_bd/mahout-core-0.9-cdh5.2.0-job.jar,./lib_bd/mahout-core-0.9-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/mahout-examples-0.9-cdh5.2.0-job.jar,./lib_bd/mahout-examples-0.9-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/mahout-integration-0.9-cdh5.2.0.jar,./lib_bd/mahout-math-0.9-cdh5.2.0.jar") --class WordCount.WordCount.WordCountSpark --master local[4] WordCount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Set hdfs master address with file address. likes as

```
  hdfs://master:9000/fileaddress
```